# Is there a trace inequality for the product of a sequence of hermitian postive definite matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, inequalities

Let $A$ and $B$ be two Hermitian matrices with positive eigenvalues. 
Let $k>0$ be a integer.
Let $P=(P_1,P_2,\dots,P_{2k})$ be a sequence of $k$ $A$s and $k$ $B$s in any given order.

Do we have
${\rm tr}\,\prod^{2k}_{i=1} P_i \leq {\rm tr}\,A^k B^k$ ?

Answer (score 6):

Although the general inequality is false (counterexamples can be found easily), for words where $A$ and $B$ occur in pairs, a stronger inequality is known. Indeed, a classic theorem of [Ando and Hiai (1994)](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0024379594904847) yields that for $A, B \ge 0$ and arbitrary reals $p_1,\ldots,p_k \ge 0$ we have
\begin{equation*}
  \text{tr}|A^{p_1}B^{p_1}\cdots A^{p_k}B^{p_k}| \le \text{tr}|A^{p_1+\cdots p_k}B^{p_1+\cdots+p_k}|,
\end{equation*}
where $|X|=(X^*X)^{1/2}$ denotes the matrix absolute value.

---

**Remark.** 
An easy way to obtain counterexamples for $3\times 3$ matrices similar to the one mentioned in **Francois**'s answer is to use matrices of the form (the values are somewhat arbitrary, other choices also work):
\begin{equation*}
 X = \begin{bmatrix}a & b& 1\\ 0 & c & -2\\ 0 &0 &0\end{bmatrix},\quad
 Y = \begin{bmatrix}p & q& 1\\ 0 & r & -1\\ 0 &0 &-1\end{bmatrix},
\end{equation*}
then to define $A=XX^T$ and $B=YY^T$. Then, try to numerically minimize the quantity $g(a,b,c,p,q,r) := \text{tr}(A^5B^5)-\text{tr}(A^4BAB^4)$. Doing so, for instance in Mathematica, easily yields $g<0$, and thus, a desired counterexample. By playing around with different $X$ and $Y$, one can easily generate additional counterexamples.

Comment: Just curious, which theorem is it in the Ando-Hiai paper?

Comment: Theorem 4.1 (actually, it's corollary lists a stronger log majorization from which the above trace inequality follows).

Comment: (the above comment should read: "actually *its* corollary....")

Answer (score 5):

A counterexample was apparently first found by [Plevnik (2016)](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3552962) [(pdf)](http://www.insa.nic.in/writereaddata/UpLoadedFiles/IJPAM/Vol47_2016_3_ART09.pdf):
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}76&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
B = \begin{bmatrix}20&-14&13\\-14&2880&3100\\13&3100&3380\end{bmatrix}
$$
give
$$
\operatorname{tr} A^4BAB^4 = 7608677695167720100 > 7566365725138281700 = \operatorname{tr} A^5B^5.
$$
To get one with $A$ positive definite as requested, replace entry $A_{22}$ by $0.01$: the two traces become
$$
7584680876077508226.18611992\ \ > \ \ 7566365725573314229.03610008.
$$

Comment: @Suvrit A 2 x 2 example could be interesting; before posting this I tried and failed generating one with numpy.random.

Comment: Actually, it seems that my $2\times 2$ counterexamples may have been due to "numerical error" --- I tried to obtain them by solving a numerical minimization problem. The $3\times 3$ case seems easier! I take back my previous comment.